# Change layout template in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, templates

The old `Android Studio` used to create the layout files using `RelativeLayout`, but the new one use `ConstraintLayout`, and this let me **very pissed off** >:[ , cause it have to import and sync... I really do not like.

I do not used to use both (`RelativeLayout` or `ConstraintLayout`), I prefer `LinearLayout` vertical, but I did not find how I can change the layout template in order to Android Studio create a layout using LinearLayout vertical, Anyone knows?

I looked for in `Preferences` -> `File and Code Templates` however I didn't find where I can change the xml layout template...

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can do that, so just replace relative with linear in the xml & don't forget to add to add the orientation

Comment: Thx, I was hoping I could swap to create the layout automatically, so unfortunately it does not ...

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the content in the layout file, and use the linear layout in that file